# Parameter binding object [FromBody] not optional

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-web-api, swagger, swashbuckle

I'm using WebAPI and Swashbuckle to test and generate client code.
In my web application I have a method with an object as parameter:

```
[Route("Orders/SendReport")]
        [HttpPost]
        public HttpResponseMessage Orders(string email,[FromBody]ReportOrders reportOrders){
   ...
}
```

In SwaggerUI this method, in the DataType section of this object parameter, shows  this example:

```
**Model:**
ReportOrders {
date1 (string, optional),
date2 (string, optional),
status (string, optional),
codformula (string, optional)
}
```

Is there a way to make those parameters (which obviously are the properties of the ReportOrders class) not optional? This is the current ReportOrders class:

```
namespace Myapp.Models
{
    public class ReportOrders
    {
        public DateTime date1 { get; set; }
        public DateTime date2 { get; set; }
        public string status { get; set; }
        public string codformula { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Comment: Could you add your `ReportOrders` class definition to the question?

Comment: Sure, I already did

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to mark the properties in the model as `[Required]`:

```
public class ReportOrders
{
    [Required]
    public DateTime? date1 { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public DateTime date2 { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public string status { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public string codformula { get; set; }
}
```

I also made the DateTimes Nullable since otherwise you can't know if they were populated or not.

Comment: I've found (only today) that Models need a reference to System.ComponentModels.DataAnnotations  and that the annotations need to be System DataAnnotations, not just Dapper annotations [if you happen to be using Dapper as your ORM] (because VS2017 identifies these as ambiguously defined annotations.

Comment: I guess Dapper has an attribute with the same name? Yes, other systems wouldn't work with that since they are searching for the data annotations one.